# SaxonC EE 11.2 "TransformFromFile()" produces empty output

Tags: c++, xml, xslt, saxon, saxon-c

my C++ code :

```
SaxonProcessor* processor = new SaxonProcessor(false);
    processor->setcwd( Current Working Directory );
    Xslt30Processor* xslt = processor->newXslt30Processor();

    XdmNode* xmlfile = processor->parseXmlFromFile( Some Xml File );
    XsltExecutable* xslte = xslt->compileFromFile(Some Xsl File);
    xslte->setOutputFile(Output File);

    xslte->transformToFile(xmlfile);
```

This works when i use "Xslt30Processor::TransformFiletoFile()" but this somehow doesn't.

Comment: So what exactly happens, the set output file is created but empty or you don't get any output file created?

Comment: The output File gets created but its empty

Comment: Im dont think it has anything to do with the xml and xslt files , because the transformation works with TransformFiletoFile()

Comment: Let's see what @ond1 has to say once he sees the question.

Comment: Hi Martin , I tried "TransformToString()" and it works , so ill just stick to that for now

Comment: I have create the bug issue: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5374 for the bug against  transformToFile

Answer (score 1):

I will raise a bug issue against transformToFile(). However if you use `applyTemplatesReturningFile` as a workaround it does work:

```
SaxonProcessor* processor = new SaxonProcessor(false);
processor->setcwd( Current Working Directory );
Xslt30Processor* xslt = processor->newXslt30Processor();
XdmNode* xmlfile = processor->parseXmlFromFile( Some Xml File );
XsltExecutable* xslte = xslt->compileFromFile(Some Xsl File);
xslte->setInitialMatchSelection(xmlfile);
xslte->applyTemplatesReturningFile(Output File);
```

Comment: Depending on what the stylesheet does (e.g. have global variables trying to access the input document) it might help to set `xslte->setGlobalContextItem(xmlfile)` as well, I guess.

Comment: @ond1 it doesn't work , i tried it and it says : Error: The initial match selection has not been set. Please set it using setInitialMatchSelection or setInitialMatchSelectionFile

Comment: @ibrahimmuhmudusmani, does it really give that error on `applyTemplatesReturningFile` after you call `xslte->setInitialMatchSelection(xmlfile);` first? I am pretty sure I converted my failing test case using `transformToFile` into a working example using the approach O'Neil outlined above. Don't have access to the source right now, if you still have problems let's look into an example tomorrow.